# Unable to pre fill Data coming from api, in my multiple dynamic tab depended forms angular

Tags: angular, dynamic-forms

```
<mat-tab [label]='customCTAArray[tabi].controls.name.value ? customCTAArray[tabi].controls.name.value : "CTA  "+ i' *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3,4,5] | slice:0:selectedProductDropDown ; let tabi=index" >
    <div class="cta-product-card">
        <!-- TEST -->
        <form class="common-form" [formGroup]="customCTAArray[tabi]" >
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" variant="standard">
                <mat-label>Name *</mat-label>
                <input matInput value="Product name" formControlName="name" />
                <mat-error *ngIf="formNameError">Please provide name</mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
            <br>
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" variant="standard">
                <mat-label>Link* </mat-label>
                <input matInput value="www.degpeg.com" formControlName="link" />
                <mat-error *ngIf="formLinkError">Please provide product link</mat-error>      </mat-form-field>
            <br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <h5>
                     Upload Image*
                     <!-- <img src="assets/images/studio/info.svg" alt="info" /> -->
                </h5>
                <div class="upload-wrapper">
                    <div class="file-upload" *ngIf="customCTAArray[tabi].controls['image'].value">          
                        <!-- <img src="assets/images/studio/profile.jpeg" alt="img" />                    -->
                        <img [src]="customCTAArray[tabi].controls['image'].value"  alt="img"  />
                    </div>
                    <!-- <div class="file-upload">
                        <img src="assets/images/studio/profile.jpeg" alt="img" />
                    </div> -->
                    </div>
                    <label for="uploadCTAFile" class="btn btn-pink btn-auto">
                        <input type="file" id="uploadCTAFile" name="uploadCTAFile" multiple="multiple" (change)="selectedCustomizedCtaFile($event, tabi)" class="hide" />
                        <img src="assets/images/studio/upload.svg" alt="upload" />
                    </label> 
                </div>
```

Comment: The question is unclear, please provide more information(share .TS file as well) and a little bit more explanation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.